# Jekyll with client-side Browserify (Watchify) js file which require environment variable/access token/api keys

Tags: javascript, jekyll, browserify, github-pages, mailgun

The background of the problem is: I want to use [MailGun](https://mailgun.com)'s JS SDK to add email contact functionalities on my [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) website.

There are 3 main challenges I faced:

1. client-side `require` nodejs packages (which I use `watchify.js` and `browserify.js` to generate a bundle.js )
2. keep my mailgun API KEY secret as an environment variable.
3. A proxy server to bypass CORS limitation, as indicated in [Mailgun.js's NOTE](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-js#mailgunjs-).

Now **this questions focus on the first two**, and  any friends who can help introduce the proper way to solve challenge 3 will be also be greatly appreciated.

From what I saw online, [`Jekyll-contentful-data-import`](https://github.com/contentful/jekyll-contentful-data-import#hiding-space-and-access-token-in-public-repositories) seems like the standard or better way to hide env variables or api keys of the sort hidden from public repo. But **I don't know how I could use Liquid Template's `{{}}` and `browserify` at the same time.**

More specifically, the usual pipeline is js files being browserified then injected as a `<script>` into the HTML page. Or I add empty FrontMatter to my js file and use Liquid's object to invoke my environment variable. Now how to invoke Liquid-fill ***first*** then feed to browserify's pipeline to process `require` packages?

Thanks for your time!!